# Jasmine error while testing redux dispatch

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, jasmine

I'm throwing a coin in the ocean after spending a couple hours trying to fix an ngRedux testing error.

Here is the component itself, as you can see, it's calling the ModuleActions:

```
@Component
class TestedClass {
  constructor(private actions: ModuleActions) {}

  restoreDefault() {
    this.action.reloadPageModule(true);
  }  
}
```

Here is the module action class, I'm using an if to dispatch the action or not, because I also call it from an epic:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModuleActions {
  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<PageModules>) {}

  ...

  reloadPageModule(dispatch?: boolean) {
    if(dispatch) {
      this.ngRedux.dispatch({
        type: ModuleActions.RELOAD_PAGE_MODULES,
        meta: { status: 'success' }
      });
    } else {
      return {
        type: ModuleActions.RELOAD_PAGE_MODULES,
        meta: { status: 'success' }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my testedClass component test:

```
it('should fire the reload page module action', () => {
  const executeActionSpy = spyOn(component['action'], 'loadSucceeded');
  component.restoreDefault();

  expect(executeActionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})

...
const compileAndCreate = () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
       ...
      ],
      providers: [
        ModuleActions,
        NgRedux
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    })
...
```

This is giving me a `this.ngRedux.dispatch() is not a function` error when called from the

Comment: Hi, have you had any luck with this? I have just hit this problem myself and have no idea what to do sadly.

Comment: hi @SebastianG, I removed NgRedux from my providers in my TestBed.configureTestingModule, and added an import for NgReduxTestingModule instead. I added an answer to my own question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, I modified my test to use an import of NgReduxTestingModule instead of a providers of NgRedux:

```
import { NgReduxTestingModule } from '@angular-redux/store/testing';



TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgReduxTestingModule, ...],
      providers: [
        ...
```